# Magento 2 Migration Products Not Displaying

Tags: php, magento, migration, magento2

Hi I recently migrated my site from magento 1.9 to 2.1.
Everything looked good apart from the products now no longer show on the front end of the site.
However they do show counts in the layered menu on the left and they show up in the admin and when you use the search at the top.

It appears they dont show in the main grid view.
Has anyone else had this issue or know what the problem may be?

I have tried reindexing and clearing the cache multiple times now too.

The website in question can be seen at http://dev.missbella.co.uk

Thanks!

[Screenshot of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8WG7.png)

Comment: Please update a product from admin

Comment: @Shine Thats strange I changed the product title on one product slightly then the products showed up but changed it back and now they dont again.
I tried changing it back again but now they dont show.

Comment: It's magento 2 bug please change the category and check

Comment: You can use mass update product from backend for all products

Comment: @Shine Thanks for the reply, do you mean change the category of a product or change the actual category?
I have tried to add a new category under new in called category and assign a product however now that just gives me a 404 page.

I did change a product category it showed for a second but then I refreshed and it disappeared again. I am surprised Magento 2 is available considering the state its in...

Comment: @Shine I reindexed and the product I assigned to this category now shows. http://dev.missbella.co.uk/new-in/category.html
Does this mean I need to reassign all my products?
Or is there a quick way of fixing this?

Comment: I can't find the route issue but it's about database entry issue some entry didn't delete

Comment: In my case when I update the product it's showing so mass update I used to update all products just any fields

Comment: I think clear the cache and reindex all

Comment: @Shine I turned on developer mode and now I know why they are not showing :( 
There are a number of products out of stock and I get this error
Configurable product "MB249" does not have sub-products

I found the issue thread on github but there is no apparent fix yet
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5762

Comment: Ok thanks anything helped you please an up vote for my comments